# Why is the $row array not populated with query values

Tags: php, mysql

I know my conn is good and the direct SQL produces the desired output, but my $row variable is not getting values from the -> FETCH()

Similar fetch() working in other code blocks

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT firstname,vcode FROM users WHERE email = ? AND verifydate IS NULL AND active = 0");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
   $row = $stmt->fetch();
   $firstname = $row[0];
   $vcode = $row[1];
}
```

No error msgs -- simply $row[] values empty

Comment: `print_r($row)` gives what?

Comment: have you pasted the query into mysql CLI and replaced params with real values to see if the qry works?

Answer (score 1):

In `mysqli`, `$stmt->fetch()` doesn't return the row, it just returns `true` or `false` to indicate whether a row could be fetched. You need to use `$stmt->fetch_row()` to get a numerically-indexed row, or `$stmt->fetch_assoc()` to get an associative array.

`$stmt->fetch()` is used along with `$stmt->bind_result()`, e.g.

```
$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $vcode);
$stmt->fetch();
```

If you see similar code that works in other applications, they must be using `PDO` rather than `mysqli`.